# Showing three layouts in a signle layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

I want to show three layouts such as first_layout, second_layout, and list_item in activity_user_profile.xml. Some parts of second_layout and list_item are not showing as seen in figure.

[image].

first_layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Second_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Main3Activity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comment"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Insert"
    android:onClick="insert"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_user_profile.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/first_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<include layout="@layout/second_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


<include layout="@layout/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to improve the result layout?

Comment: Why aren't you using ScrollView ?

Comment: why you want to use three layout when this can be done with single layout ?

Comment: I donnot know how I can make them in single layout

Answer (score 0):

Use `ScrollView`. First place a `ScrollView` and add your widgets inside that. That should work.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <!-- Add your widgets here -->
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you explain more? where should I add scrollview?

Comment: where should I add widgets? can you tell me exactly? thank you

Comment: See the updated answer.ScrollView can handle only one view.So add all your views inside this LinearLayout. And don't add 3 layouts. Use a single layout

Answer (score 0):

Use `ScrollView`, in that you create a `childview(Linear or Relative layout)` as `ScrollView` accepts only one child. Then add your 3 layouts in the childview.

```
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:fontify="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:fillViewport="true" >

         <LinearLayout  // child view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical” >

         <TextView   // your 1st view
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           android:text="Large Text"
           android:id="@+id/textView3"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <LinearLayout  // your 2nd view
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           >

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Subject"
           android:id="@+id/textView" />

       <EditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/editTextName" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Comment"
           android:id="@+id/textView2" />

       <EditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/editTextAddress" />

       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Insert"
           android:onClick="insert"
           android:id="@+id/button" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/textViewResult" />
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout  // your 3rd view
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
       <ListView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/listView" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/id"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingBottom="2dip"
           android:paddingTop="6dip"
           android:textStyle="bold" />


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/name"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:paddingBottom="2dip"
           android:textStyle="bold"/>


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/address"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="left"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

                  </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

       </ScrollView>
```

Comment: if it is possible for your explain with code, I am beginner thank you